# How can I fix this apt update error?

Tags: apt, gnome-terminal

```
Err:17 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (40367 != 55406). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 40.65.182.21 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:55406 [weak]
   - SHA512:375df5cd3f502bd79e283f335e82aaa100345ebc687f4d080f18ebd4fb5d61a1cd09468031365bf054a5ab37dd9899bc9fbdcd589d998e198086a68e1ca1251a
   - SHA256:e05badc92e0971793e10fed74f79accb6b271cbf94de4d268f033082629bf459
   - SHA1:4bc4a9653010af3300084b9069004c33adc557af [weak]
   - MD5Sum:855c0d84194a55c5a3fe33be18bae9b0 [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 18 Nov 2021 19:12:32 +0000
Get:18 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages [56.3 kB]
Err:18 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages
  
Get:19 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages [56.4 kB]
Err:19 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages
  
Fetched 10.4 kB in 8s (1,319 B/s)                        
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  File has unexpected size (40367 != 55406). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 40.65.182.21 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:55406 [weak]
    - SHA512:375df5cd3f502bd79e283f335e82aaa100345ebc687f4d080f18ebd4fb5d61a1cd09468031365bf054a5ab37dd9899bc9fbdcd589d998e198086a68e1ca1251a
    - SHA256:e05badc92e0971793e10fed74f79accb6b271cbf94de4d268f033082629bf459
    - SHA1:4bc4a9653010af3300084b9069004c33adc557af [weak]
    - MD5Sum:855c0d84194a55c5a3fe33be18bae9b0 [weak]
   Release file created at: Thu, 18 Nov 2021 19:12:32 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/main/binary-armhf/Packages.bz2  
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/main/binary-arm64/Packages.bz2  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Wait until the mirror sync is complete?

Comment: I have changed the mirror and waited for the sync but seems like nothing is happening. This started to happen when I tried to install codeblocks.